# Character Counter from "The C Programming Language" Not Working As I Expected

Tags: c, character

I am reading through "The C Programming Language", and working through all the exercises with CodeBlocks. But I cannot get my character counter to work, despite copying it directly from the book. The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    long nc;

    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

When I run the program, it opens a window I can type in, but when I hit enter all that happens is it skips down a line and I can keep typing, but I think it's supposed to print the number of characters.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
```

means that it keeps reading until the end of input — *not* until the end of a line. (`EOF` is a special constant meaning "end of file".) You need to end input (probably with Ctrl-D or with Ctrl-Z) to see the total number of characters that were input.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to terminate on EOL (end of line), replace EOF with '\n':

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    long nc;

    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Enter is not EOF.  Depending on your OS, Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z should act as EOF on standard input.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. But Ctrl-D and Ctrl-Z both don't work. They type ^D and ^Z respectively. Anything else  it could be, or somewhere to find out what it is?

Comment: @user1624005: You may need to type Ctrl-Z followed by Enter.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem tonight, too. Finally found out that Ctrl-D on Linux worked. You build the source file using cc, and start the program and input a word, then press Ctrl-D twice when finished typing. The number that the program countered will be printed just behind the very word you just typed, and the program terminates immediately. Just like this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above answer provided by nujabse is correct. But recently coming across this issue myself and researching the answer, I would like to add why.

Using Ctrl+C tells the terminal to send a SIGINT to the current foreground process, which by default translates into terminating the application.

Ctrl+D tells the terminal that it should register a EOF on standard input, which bash interprets as a desire to exit.

[What's the difference between ^C and ^D](https://superuser.com/a/169055/471062)